# Fiddler TextView to JMeter Body Data

Tags: jmeter, jmx, fiddler

I had converted fiddler .har file to jmeter .jmx file and wanted to do some correlation on the script. However, the conversion does not seem to display the Body Data. Is there a way to go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely the issue with the conversion.
May be you can signup for [octoperf](https://octoperf.com/) and upload your har there.

It will allow you to convert the har to jmx and you can   correlate by searching the parameters in the response. It provides exceptional features in terms of creating a testplan.

You should give it a try building the jmx there and export it to your local to run in your jmeter.

Comment: Tried and this has worked and made it easier, excellent

Answer (score 2):

Check "Parameters" tab, it might be the case the XML body is there.

Otherwise just copy the XML payload and paste it to the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler

Also be aware that it should be possible to [chain Fiddler to JMeter as the upstream proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/chaintoupstreamproxy) and [Resend the request](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/generate-traffic/tasks/resendrequest) so JMeter could capture it and create appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

More information: [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: Tried the copy and paste method and it has worked, haven't tried chaining it yet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are showing correct details in your question ? Found it misleading or maybe mistake ?

You request in the fiddler showing `AccountLoginRequest` but in JMeter you are showing `GetAccountConfigurationRequest`

[image]

But there is a direct way, export your calls from fiddler as `Curl` and import it directly in JMeter.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Import from cURL also does not provide the request. You are right about the AccountLoginRequest and GetAccountConfigurationRequest - mistake on my part